# Set jQuery Timers to DIV Children in For Loop

Tags: jquery, for-loop, timer

I have 9 DIVs inside of one main DIV. I'm trying to apply the following logic to each child so they animate one after the next. Here's what I have and it's not working. Suggestions/advice greatly appreciated.

```
var allReds = $('#redSwatches').children();

for (var allReds = 0; allReds < 9; allReds++) {
    var timerTwo = setTimeout(function() {
        $('#red1').addClass('scale');
    }, 5000);

    var timerThree = setTimeout(function() {
        clearTimeout(timerTwo);
        $('#red1').removeClass('scale');
    }, 5500);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you have 9 `div`s inside one `div#redSwatches`. There are a few things wrong with the code.

You're assigning the child `div`s to the variable `allReds`. Then you are assigning `0` to the same variable.

Also, the loop only animates a single element `#red1` 9 times, but those 9 animations are all happening at the same time. Also, `clearTimeout` seems useless here.

Now here's what I think it should be:

```
var allReds = $('#redSwatches').children();    // get the children

for (var i = 0; i < 9; i++) {    // use another counter i
    setTimeout(function() {    // since the animation happens once, you don't need to save it in a variable
        $( allReds[i] ).addClass('scale');    // get next child allReds[i]
    }, i*500);    // ..and animate one after another every .5 second

    setTimeout(function() {
        $( allReds[i] ).removeClass('scale');
    }, i*500 + 500);    // second animation on same element, .5 second after it started
}
```

Comment: Thank you Salman!! I see what you mean. The children divs didn't animate though. I ran a console.log test and it's hitting all the children each iteration. Then I tried a console.log on:

$('#red' + i)

and it's hitting one child, on each iteration, but the last div remains up for an extended period, then scales back down. Can you please provide more assistance. This must be close. Thank you, Salman.

Comment: <pre>

    for (var i = 0; i < 9; i++) {    // use another counter i
    setTimeout(function() {    // since the animation happens once, you don't need to save it in a variable
        $('#red' + i).addClass('scale');    // get next child allReds[i]
    }, i*500);    // ..and animate one after another every .5 second

    console.log($('#red' + i));
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('#red' + i).removeClass('scale');
    }, i*500 + 500);    // second animation on same element, .5 second after it started
}

<pre>

Comment: I can't figure out how to past code. I've tried <pre> and <code> and indenting 4 spaces.

Comment: Use jsfiddle.net to create a fiddle and post the link here.